# PHP Error:Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.smartsheet.com:443

Tags: php, ssl, curl, smartsheet-api

I am attempting to connect to the smart sheets API with PHP/cURL.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/xxxxxxxxx/rows");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
        "[{\"toTop\":true, \"cells\": [ "
        . "{\"columnId\": xxxxxxxx, \"value\": description},"
        . "{\"columnId\": xxxxxxxx, \"value\": amount},"
        . "{\"columnId\": xxxxxxxx, \"value\": po},"
        . "{\"columnId\": xxxxxxxx, \"value\": wo},"
        . "{\"columnId\": xxxxxxxx, \"value\": contractor},"
        . "{\"columnId\": xxxxxxxx, \"value\": vendorcode},"
        . "{\"columnID\": xxxxxxxx, \"value\": notes}]");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxx";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

For some reason every time it runs I get the following error:

> Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.smartsheet.com:443

I have tried to change around the SSL_Version but that doesn't fix the problem either. I know that all my numbers (token, sheetnum, column num) are correct. I have tried going through other solutions of people who were working with other api's but still could not find the answer. Does any one have any ideas on how to fix this?

Thank you,
Joshua

Comment: Have you checked the following? http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html

Comment: I just went through it and I still cant seem to locate the problem. This is my first time working with cURL so some of the protocols are foreign to me. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

This enforces SSLv3, a protocol which is obsoleted for some time for security reasons. And, [looking at the configuration of the server](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.smartsheet.com) it does not support SSLv3 which is similar to most other servers.

I recommend to simple remove this line and let curl pick the best version by itself.

> I have tried to change around the SSL_Version but that doesn't fix the problem either.

It might not fix the problem in that you don't get the expected the response from the server. It might remove the specific SSL problem you are facing though so that you continue with other problems you code might have. Look closely at any error messages which might change.

Comment: First off, Thank you for your response. Second, I tried pulled it out but the problem persisted. So I tried to force the curl to use TLSv1.2 as pointed out in the link you supplied. Any other ideas on how to fix it? It will not respond with an error number, just the error

Comment: @JoshuaAverbuch: do you get every time exactly the same error of *Unknown SSL protocol error*? Can you provide the configuration of your environment, i.e. curl version and openssl version (in case curl is used with openssl bindings). See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-version.php on how to get these information.

Comment: version_number 462597 version 2 ssl_version_number 1597 ssl_version 0 libz_version 7.15.5 host i386-redhat-linux-gnu age OpenSSL/0.9.8b features 1.2.3 protocols Array

Comment: @JoshuaAverbuch: __OpenSSL/0.9.8b__ - this is a terrible old  (11 years) and since years unsupported version of OpenSSL. It has no support for TLS 1.2 which means that you cannot enforce it. It has lots of bugs. Similar your version of curl is more than 10 years old and lots of bugs got fixed in the mean time. My guess is that your problems would vanish if you would use an up-to-date system.

Comment: I will look into this. Thank you very much